# "Module" versus "Abelian Group" of the Integers, German Language usage circa 1962

Tags: group-theory, modules, definition, math-history

In the highly respectable [BBFSK](https://mitpress.mit.edu/contributors/h-behnke) Vol I B2 we are told that the integers form a *module* with respect to addition.  Where by module they mean a set together with an operation (+) defined in it satisfying the requirement of

1. associativity and commutativity,
2. a neutral element applicable to every element,
3. an inverse to every element.

In a footnote they say this is also called a commutative (or Abelian) group.

That is not how I would typically enumerate the laws/axioms/properties of an Abelian group, but it is consistent with the familiar definition.  The term *module* is otherwise unfamiliar to me.  I've been told that the use of the term in this way is non-standard.  Is that the case?  If so, how is this similar and different from the currently accepted definition?

Comment: It's an older terminology, but it checks out.

Comment: It's a largely obsolete term, but some authors used to use "module" to denote an additive subgroup of a ring, not necessarily a subring or an ideal. It's sometimes seen in describing subgroups of a ring of algebraic integers.

Comment: Of course, in German the word would be *Modul*.

Comment: Every abelian group, and thus the integers as a group, are modules over the integers as a ring.

Comment: *That is not how I would typically enumerate the [axioms] of an abelian group.* it isn’t? It sounds like a pretty standard description of an abelian group to me. What’s different?

Comment: @rschwieb See page 13 for "group" and ($\alpha$)  on page 24 for "Abelian group" :  http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/43006

Comment: @StevenHatton Well, there you have it: not a big surprise an early 20th century text from a physics point of view uses a definition that's not very modern.  It can, however, be worked out to be an equivalent formulation.

Comment: @rschwieb My perception is that Weyl was one of the most significant group theoreticians ever to live.  I note that his 3 laws ($\alpha$) are identical to the laws used in BBFSK to construct the module of the integers.  Until now, I had never noticed the striking similarity between the two developments.

Comment: @StevenHatton That is so, but time (often) changes all things.  The three points in your post are a very common description of an Abelian group.

Comment: I usually see something like (1) closure (2) associativity (3) identity (4) inverse then  (5) commutativity (if applicable.)  In the unlikely chance that I ever write something intended for publication, I will certainly explain why I chose a certain set of axioms, and how they relate to the other common sets of axioms.  I like Weyl's because they are minimal.  Identity and inverse are theorems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Nowadays", and for as long as I have known,  a *module over a ring* is a notion that *generalises* that of a *vector space over a field*.

Since apparently a vector space is an abelian group, well, there you have it.

Comment: Also note that any abelian group is a module over $\Bbb Z$ and vice versa.

Comment: Apparently they are showing that the set of endomorphisms of a module forms a ring with composition as the multiplicative operator.  So the "over the ring" part is redundant.  If I am drawing the correct conclusion, the only such set of endomorphisms of $\left(\mathbb{Z},+\right)$ is the set of standard multiplicative products.  That is, composition of **the** endomorphisms of the  the module is identical to standard multiplication.

Comment: @StevenHatton "over a ring" is *not* redundant when specifying a module structure. An abelian group can have different structures using different rings.

Comment: @rschwieb Indeed.  I see what you mean.  In my current situation the module precedes the ring in terms of the order of development.  And the ring is a direct manifestation of the module.  Beyond that, I've reached mental saturation.  I need to give this time to sink in.